# Passing a stream thorugh IPC

Tags: stream, electron, childwindow, mainwindow, ipcrenderer

Working on video calling project, My Call is displayed in the mainWindow and when I Click On a button , I need the Call to be on another Window. but am not able to send stream through the IPC , so the only possible way I can see is to start a separate call in the other window. Is there anything like createPortal(react) where I can just renderer the same component in the mainwindow without breaking the flow to the other window?

I haven't found any solutions yet